# Using DataFrame Columns as id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know how to transform this DataFrame in a way that the column names become a query ID (keeping the df length) and the values are flattened. I am trying to learn about 'learning to rank' algorithms. Thanks for the help.

```
                 AUD=X    CAD=X    CHF=X  ...    SGD=X      THB=X     ZAR=X
Date                                    ...                              
2004-06-30       NaN  1.33330  1.25040  ...  1.72090  40.834999   6.12260
2004-07-01       NaN  1.33160  1.24900  ...  1.71420  40.716999   6.16500
2004-07-02       NaN  1.32270  1.23320  ...  1.71160  40.638000   6.12010
2004-07-05       NaN  1.32470  1.23490  ...  1.71480  40.658001   6.15010
2004-07-06       NaN  1.32660  1.23660  ...  1.71530  40.765999   6.20990
             ...      ...      ...  ...      ...        ...       ...
2021-07-19  1.352997  1.26169  0.91853  ...  1.35630  32.810001  14.38950
2021-07-20  1.362546  1.27460  0.91850  ...  1.36360  32.840000  14.53068
2021-07-21  1.362600  1.26751  0.92123  ...  1.36621  32.820000  14.59157
2021-07-22  1.360060  1.25689  0.91757  ...  1.36383  32.849998  14.57449
2021-07-23  1.354922  1.25640  0.91912  ...  1.35935  32.879002  14.69760
```

Comment: There's the `set_index` method, but it appears to me that `Date` is already the index. Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Apologies, that was not a good explanation. Essentially, I need to comprise the dataframe in two columns. Hence, the idea of transforming column names in IDs.

Comment: does the `=X` have some significance? Are there columns where there's a letter other than X?

Comment: No, the =X has no significance. No additional columns.

Comment: There are definitely additional columns as the `...` in the example represents data that's omitted for visualization purposes. Can you make a minimal example with the expected input and output?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The minimal example doesn't need to have every column as we just need something that illustrates the desired transformation.

Comment: Right there are 17 columns, but all of them have the same =X structure. I am looking for something like this:                                                                      
 query_id       AUD       CAD          CHF           Rank
0           0  0.73730  0.725224  0.104532     1
1           0  0.129208  0.607500  0.264306     9
2           0  0.604539  0.354553  0.914650     1
3           0  0.082171  0.135789  0.103814     3
4           0  0.108583  0.633263  0.215662     7

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Steele. I would think about it in two steps, first create an ID, such as AUD, CAD, etc and group the DataFrame by that ID perhaps. I am just don't know how to do that.

Comment: I don't see ` 0.73730 0.725224 0.104532` in the example so I still can't infer what the transformation is. Try editing your question to better illustrate the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
            AUD=X   CAD=X   CHF=X   SGD=X      THB=X   ZAR=X
Date                                                        
2004-06-30    NaN  1.3333  1.2504  1.7209  40.834999  6.1226
2004-07-01    NaN  1.3316  1.2490  1.7142  40.716999  6.1650
2004-07-02    NaN  1.3227  1.2332  1.7116  40.638000  6.1201
2004-07-05    NaN  1.3247  1.2349  1.7148  40.658001  6.1501
2004-07-06    NaN  1.3266  1.2366  1.7153  40.765999  6.2099

In [6]: df.columns = df.columns.str.slice(0, -2)

In [8]: df.T
Out[8]: 
Date  2004-06-30  2004-07-01  2004-07-02  2004-07-05  2004-07-06
AUD          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
CAD     1.333300    1.331600      1.3227    1.324700    1.326600
CHF     1.250400    1.249000      1.2332    1.234900    1.236600
SGD     1.720900    1.714200      1.7116    1.714800    1.715300
THB    40.834999   40.716999     40.6380   40.658001   40.765999
ZAR     6.122600    6.165000      6.1201    6.150100    6.209900
```

I'm still not super clear on the requirements, but this transformation might help.